# How to add one space in the end of the line?

Tags: unix, sed, sh, darwin

I'm using shell script and I want to add a space at the end of the line if the last characters are: ,.-

I've tried `sed 's/,.-\r\n/,.- \r\n/g' part2.out > part3.out` but it didn't work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$` to match the end of line, and escape the `.`:

```
sed 's/,\.-$/,.- /'
```

You should probably use `&` as well, and you might prefer to only do the replacement if the line matches:

```
sed '/,\.-$/s//& /'
```

Since your lines appear to have DOS line endings, you might want to take care of them with `dos2unix` or some other utility more suited to that.  One simple (but not robust) solution is to just delete the `\r` characters, since you almost certainly do not actually want them in the data:

```
tr -d \\r < part2.out | sed 's/,\.-$/& /' > part3.out
```

is probably good enough.  If Jaypal is correct and you are trying to match any line that ends in any of the characters `,`, `.`, or `-` instead of ending with the string `,.-`, then you want:

```
sed 's/[,.-]$/& /'
```

Comment: It didn't work. If I use only $ it works but when I put it together with some characters it doesn't do the job!

Comment: What do you mean by "put it together with some characters"?  Are you getting false positives?  Use `\.` instead of `.`.  (Answer edited.)

Comment: The `tr` worked well, but it removes the `\r`, how can I add again the `\r` in the `sed`?

Comment: With gnu sed, I believe you can use `\r` in the replacement string, but with BSD sed I think you cannot.  Try installing gnu sed, or use perl, or unix2dos

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
sed 's/\([\.,-]\)$/\1 /g' input_file
```

#### Test: `cat -vet` will show you special non printing characters

```
$ cat -vet ff
col1a col2a col3a col4a col5a col6a XXXXXXAAAAA col8a ...$
col1b col2b col3b col4b col5b col6b XXXXXXBBBBB col8b ..-$
col1c col2c col3c col4c col5c col6c XXXXXXCCCCC col8c ..,$
col1d col2d col3d col4d col5d col6d XXXXXXDDDDD col8d ...$

$ sed 's/\([\.,-]\)$/\1 /g' ff | cat -vet
col1a col2a col3a col4a col5a col6a XXXXXXAAAAA col8a ... $
col1b col2b col3b col4b col5b col6b XXXXXXBBBBB col8b ..- $
col1c col2c col3c col4c col5c col6c XXXXXXCCCCC col8c .., $
col1d col2d col3d col4d col5d col6d XXXXXXDDDDD col8d ... $
```

Comment: You are probably correct in interpreting the question as "any of the characters".  There's no need to escape the `.` inside the character class and doing so causes a match on lines ending in '\'. `\(\)` is probably overkill since you can use `&` instead of `\1` safely here.  (The end of line inside the match will not change anything.)

Comment: Why do you need the `g` flag?

Comment: @devnull: it's superflous here (as we only match end of lines, not anywhere in the string). But not harmfull (apart from probably a bit of overhead)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `CR+LF` line endings, you can try:

```
sed '/[.,-]\r/ {s/\r/ A/}'
```

(use `$` instead of `\r` in case of `LF` as the newline character)